# sending gifts to selected friends

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Im trying to build a facebook app using the c# sdk

Part of the brief I have been given is to allow the user to select specific friends from a list of all of there friends, the selected friends will then be sent a 'gift' (on of those pictures with text you see in facebook).

I just need to know if this is possbile. I have been googling and cant find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a canvas app, use Requests - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

If it's not, your only real fallback option is stream posting, but posting to multiple friends at once that way isn't allowed and will massively increase the spam reports of your app